# Mysqli Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to use mysql in php. Consider the following code

```php
<?php
$dname="database";
$conn=new mysqli("localhost","root","");
if($conn->connect_error){
    die("Connection failed ,Please configure username and password correctly".$conn->connect_error);
  }
echo "Connect Successfully <br>";
$sql="DROP DATABASE IF EXIST $dname";
mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
$sql="CREATE DATABASE $dname";
if(!mysqli_query($conn,$sql)){
    die("Error".$conn->error);
}
echo "Database created";
?>
```

I have checked the username and password  and made sure they have complete privilege and I can create database from command line using same credentials. I am using XAMPP .Why do I keep getting the error ?

Comment: In this line:-`$conn=new mysqli("localhost","root","");` you are not providing database name i.e its in the form of `new mysqli(host,username,password,database name)`.....and after that also check that mysql server is running or not in `xampp`